# Django south migration

Tags: django, django-south

I have added to my model the following line

```
room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
```

after that I tried to use south migrate:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp
```

but I have received the following error:

```
Running migrations for myapp:
- Nothing to migrate.
- Loading initial data for myapp.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Could you please advice me what can I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the relevant part of the tutorial: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model

(Tip: The tutorial says there are 3 steps.  You're only doing 2 of them).

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for your help! Indeed, I have omitted this step.